# How to set Text Input field to focus when user start typing on page

Tags: html

I am trying to autofocus on a text input when a user starts typing on a webpage.

i have tried this, but this is only for page load

```
<input type="text" name="text_input" autofocus>
```

How can i set it so it will focus when the user starts typing on the page

Comment: I imagine this would require JavaScript.  Probably won't be terribly pretty.  You *could* have a keypress (keyup?) even listener on the whole document object which focuses that field.  However, you'd also need to capture that first keystroke and append it to the field (since the field *wasn't* focused when the key was pressed).  And then you'd also need to maintain state to ensure that you don't *re-focus* the field over and over any time the user types in a different field.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.

```
$('body').on('keydown', function() {
    var input = $('input[name="text_input"]');

    if(!input.is(':focus')) {
        input.focus();
    }

});
```

**Edit**

If you only want this to happen once, you can set some sort of flag, like this:

```
var flag = false;

$('body').on('keydown', function() {
    var input = $('input[name="text_input"]'),


    if(!input.is(':focus') && flag === false) {
        input.focus();
        flag = true;
    }

});
```

Comment: works great, but how about if another text input is already selected on the page and the user is filling out a form, when they try to type in the form its focusing to this field

Comment: @Charles, see my edit. You'll have to play around with the logic a little bit as there are many ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Josh Beam's answer, if you want to also tack whatever key the user pressed to the end of the input you could do something like the code below. It also only triggers if the pressed key is a number or letter, so it won't take focus if the user presses an arrow key, page up, etc.

```
$('body').on('keydown', function(keyPress) {
    var input = $('input[name="text_input"]');

    if(!input.is(':focus') &&  keyPress.key.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        input.focus();
        input.val(input.val()+keyPress.key);
    }

});
```